# How to export data and piechart into excel using richfaces?

Tags: richfaces, pie-chart

I am developing a project using `RichFaces`.

My requirement is need to export data and `piechart` or `barchart`(Highchart) into `excel`.

Is it possible to do this?

If yes means any idea please....

Comment: Possible but not with RichFaces, you'll have to export it yourself. There should be some Java libraries for creating excel Excel sheets.

Comment: @Makhiel Thanks for your response. I have done this one by using jfreechart java library.